# Selecting features enclosed by another layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, select-by-location

[image]

I have 2 layers selected layers as shown in the figure below, hotosm_glp_rpads_lines (Layer 1) and LaSoufriere_Imapact_Zones(Layer 2). I want to select all the polylines in layer 1 which is bounded by layer 2 (all the polylines which are inside the brown region).

How do I do this in QGIS?

NOTE: It would be great if there is some code that can be written in the select feature by expression under the attribute table since I have to also select another set of polylines. In more detail, I need to,
I need to select polylines bounded by the brown region & also select polylines having the attribute "highway" = "primary" in the attribute table

Comment: Try the `Select by location` tool from the _Processing Toolbox_.

Comment: You could run the tools consecutively (i.e. first the `Select by location` tool and then the `Select by expression` tool with the expression `"highway" = 'primary'`, note the single quotes for values and double quotes for field names). Make sure the _Modify current selection by_ setting in both tools are set to `creating new selection`.

Comment: Try `searching a bit` in GIS stack exchange ...